# using a batch file to open lua love is giving error

Tags: lua, love2d

I just started learning love and I've tried opening love with a batch file, while it does open it gives this error

```
Error

[love "boot.lua"]:321: No code to run
Your game might be packaged incorrectly.
Make sure main.lua is at the top level of the zip.


Traceback

[love "callbacks.lua"]:228: in function 'handler'
[C]: in function 'error'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

however when dragging the whole folder inside of love it works perfectly, does somebody know how can I fix this?

Comment: What's in your bat file?  Have you "cd" to the correct directory before running love?

Comment: I assume you packed it into a .love? The most common error is that people zip the folder of the game, not the game files itself. If you open the .love e.g. using 7zip, main.lua needs to be in the root.

Answer (score 1):

### Error message

Error message indicates, that you did not set correct path to your code, so the is no code to run. It should be folder containing `main.lua`

### Simple batch file

Place the following code to file `start.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF

"C:\Program Files\LOVE\love.exe" "C:\path\to\game\folder"
```

(replace `C:\path\to\game\folder` with actual path to folder containing `main.lua` and if you have `love.exe` elsewhere, also replace it to the correct path)

And then, you can run your code by double-clicking the `start.bat` file

### Some helpful links:

[How to run your game](https://love2d.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Windows)
[Batch file example](https://love2d.org/wiki/Batch_Start)